# Mysql: performance partitions in joining tables

Tags: mysql, database, query-optimization, partitioning, database-partitioning

I have a question with partitions and joining tables in MySQL.
I have this sample schema:

```
CREATE TABLE A (
`ID` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`NAME` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
KEY `IDX_A_NAME` (`NAME`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE B (
`ID` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`VALUE` double(22,6) DEFAULT NULL,
`A_REF` BIGINT DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
KEY `IDX_A_REF` (`A_REF`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
PARTITION BY RANGE( A_REF ) (
                PARTITION p1000 VALUES LESS THAN (1000),
    PARTITION p2000 VALUES LESS THAN (2000),
    PARTITION p3000 VALUES LESS THAN (3000),
    PARTITION future VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE
                            );
```

The B partitioned table grows about 3 millon rows a month.
The partition criteria by A_REF field is because B table is being accessed with queries like this (by now, it couldn't be changed):

```
SELECT B.VALUE
FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON A.ID = B.A_REF
WHERE A.NAME = 'James'
```

So, my questions are

- When executing *EXPLAIN PARTITIONS...* with this query, all partitions are accessed in EXPLAIN output. Does it mean that all partitions are *actually* accessed in the execution? Or is it only partition information?
- Does it help that partitioning criteria was the JOIN field?
- Does partitioning help in my example?
- Is there any other approach (another partitioning criteria, etc.) that help to access a lower number of rows or the query executes faster?

I'm worried about executing this query for a year with round 40 million of rows. So, any help is very very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To speed up *that* query, get rid of partitioning.

The pruning failed (I think) because it did not have a constant with which to pick the partition.  Instead, the `JOIN` reached into all partitions.  All but one returned nothing, the one with the A_REF in it returned the row(s) just as if it had been a non-partitioned table.

There are many cases were partitioning does not help performance; you seem to have found one where it hurts.

Comment: thank you for your explanation. I can´t mark your answer as the final one, but it's helpful, and it makes all the sense for me. So, thanks.